# How to make an element jump from top to the bottom of the web page and back to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element div in a shape of a ball. What I am trying to do is, when I refresh the page I want to the ball to fall to the bottom of the webpage and then bounce back up to the top of the page.

This is my jQuery function where the ball falls to the bottom of the web page

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").animate({ top: '+=585'}, 400);
});
```

Am I using a correct approach? Should I use slideDwon and slideUp instead?

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").animate({ top: '+=585'}, 400);

   setTimeout(
     function() 
    {
      $("div").animate({ top: '-=585'}, 400);
    }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this HTML :

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myRelativeDiv">test</div>
```

1st step is to set the position of your div as "relative" :

```
.relative {
    position:relative;
}
```

2nd step is animate with Jquery (You can chain many `animate`):

```
$(function() {
   $("#myDiv").animate({ top: '+=585'}, 400).animate({ top: '0'}, 400);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/wh0dn1xw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of jQuery's animation chainability. Also, you probably shouldn't assume a static value of `585` will be suitable for every screen size. I suggest using calculated values for generating the offsets, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1cfLtp7/):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var viewportH = $(window).height();
      var elem = $('div');
      var elemH = elem.height();

      elem.animate({
          top: '+=' + (viewportH - elemH) // bottom of screen
      }, 400).animate({
          top: '-=' + (viewportH - elemH) // original position
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [jQuery UI .effect()](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/)

```js
$(function() {

  var div = $("div");
  // `elem`: element to apply bounce effect,
  // `n`: number of bounce effects to apply to `elem`
  var bounce = function bounce(elem, n) {
    var fx = function fx(el) {
      return (el || $(this))
        .effect({
          effect: "bounce",
          easing: "swing",
          duration: 400,
          distance: window.innerHeight 
                    - (el.height() + el.offset().top * 1.5),
          direction: "down",
          times: 1
        }).promise()
    };
    return fx(elem).then.apply(elem, $.map(Array(n - 1), function() {
      return fx(elem)
    }));
  };
  
  bounce(div, 1).then(function(el) {
    // do stuff when bounce effect complete
    console.log("complete", el)
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(212, 98, 44);
  border: 2px solid navy;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div></div>
```